# PyTorch Lightning wants create a folder on import due to usage of wandb, which raises error on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, wandb

So I want to build a Docker image with PyTorch Lightning that can be used with AWS lambda. However, when the function is invoked it raises an OS Error, that claims it uses a Read-only file system and wandb.py wants to write something.

I tried these things:

1. Overwrite the wandb.py file of pytroch lightning, that it does not init wandb --> Raises error
2. Execute a python script in Dockerfile, that the files are created on docker build and exist, when invoking the lambda function --> Same OS error

Does someone know a way to skip the wandb.py?

This is the error message:

```
START RequestId: ddae284d-4f32-4dc6-8160-d1fa62ba9772 Version: $LATEST
OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/inference.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pytorch_lightning as pl
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import Callback
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.swa import StochasticWeightAveraging
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/swa.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.trainer.optimizers import _get_default_scheduler_config
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer import Trainer
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.loggers import LightningLoggerBase
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loggers/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.loggers.wandb import _WANDB_AVAILABLE, WandbLogger  # noqa: F401
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loggers/wandb.py", line 34, in <module>
    import wandb
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wandb/__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    api = InternalApi()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wandb/apis/internal.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.api = InternalApi(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wandb/sdk/internal/internal_api.py", line 73, in __init__
    self._settings = Settings(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wandb/old/settings.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._global_settings.read([Settings._global_path()])
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wandb/old/settings.py", line 105, in _global_path
    util.mkdir_exists_ok(config_dir)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wandb/util.py", line 687, in mkdir_exists_ok
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
END RequestId: ddae284d-4f32-4dc6-8160-d1fa62ba9772
REPORT RequestId: ddae284d-4f32-4dc6-8160-d1fa62ba9772  Duration: 27000.33 ms   Billed Duration: 27001 ms   Memory Size: 10240 MB   Max Memory Used: 241 MB 
Unknown application error occurred
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have write access somewhere.

Then you can use [wandb environment variables](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/track/advanced/environment-variables) to modify the default location where files are saved locally, in particular look at WANDB_DIR, WANDB_CONFIG_DIR and WANDB_CACHE_DIR.